# Getting Cell Content from C# Grid Control

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0, controls, wpf-controls

I am using **System.Windows.Controls.Grid** in C# application. When the form is loaded, I added the `UIElement`s in the cells. But when I click the cell, how do I get the current `UIElement` back?

PS: I searched the web, and I found out we need to loop through the `UIElementCollection` and get the values.

But this is not a good Idea. Because, if we have 1000 Cells and it has 1000 media elements, then I need to loop through all the `UIElement`s. So suggest me how we will get the content.

My code Snippet:(Trial)

```
          private void DispImage(System.Windows.UIElement uiElement)
          {
              foreach (var item in this.grid1.Children)
                {
                    if (item is textBox1)
                    {
                        element = item;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (element != null)
                {
                    this.grid1.Children.Remove(element as UIElement);
                }

                if (uiElement != null)
                {
                    Grid.SetRow(uiElement, CurrentRow);
                    Grid.SetColumn(uiElement, CurrentColumn);
                if (this.DynamicGrid.Children.IndexOf(UIElement) == -1)
                    this.DynamicGrid.Children.Add(uiElement);
               }
            }
```

Here `UIElement` is an `ImageObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had troubles because you're using *WPF* in a very old style, *WinForms* way.

Get familiar with concepts such as *Models*, *Bindings*, *Commands* and it will solve nicely.

In your case it means:

- Create a model for your items and put it a in model collection
- Bind your model to a templated `ItemsControl`, with appropriate `ItemsPanel`
- Define a template for your items that wraps your `UIElement` in a `Button`
- Implements a `Command` to do whatever you want it to do
- Assign your `Command` to your `Button`
- ???
- Profit

In a more general way, do **not** modify the user interface directly: modify your model and let the user interface interact with it.